# Opencart: AJAX и пагинация

Tags: ajax, opencart

уважаемые!

Прикрутила простейший скрипт ajax для загрузки товаров в product/category.tpl.

```
<script>
  $('.sliderArrow').on('click', '.toPageButton', function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/catalog/controller/product/category.php',
    type: "get",
    data:  $('.toPageButton').attr('href') ,
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    },
    error: function() 
    {}          
   });
  });
</script>
```

А в результате он мне пишет: Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /catalog/controller/product/category.php on line 3. 
Файл category.php не меняла. 
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Вы напрямую переходите к файлу. Попробуйте ссылку изменить на:
`/index.php?route=product/category`.
Проблема состоит в том, что вы переходи на файл, какой содержит только класс с Category. А когда Вы через index заходите, этот файл подключает все необходимые компоненты для работы

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь вот такое в консоли выдает:
Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 0):

При ajax запросе вам необходимо обратиться к методу класса в файле product.php (скорее всего к методу **index()**)

```
url: 'index.php?route=product/product/index'
```